# azure cloud service is not aviailable after deployed to virtual network

Tags: azure-cloud-services, azure-virtual-network

my WebPortal is hosted in WebRole in a virtual network which will connect to my corp network (site-to-site). but i cannot access it by http://xxxx.cloudapp.net address. need help !

just clarify:

- I can access xxx.cloudapp.net if my project is not deployed to VNet (that means I remove NetWorkConfiguration from ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg
- I cannot access xxx.cloudapp.net after my project is in VNet. 
  I can ping successfully webrole instance IP from my Corp NetWork

1) ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg

```
  <Role name="WebRole_1">
    <ConfigurationSettings />
    <Instances count="1" />
    <Certificates />
  </Role>
  <NetworkConfiguration>
    <VirtualNetworkSite name="myVNet" />
    <AddressAssignments>
      <InstanceAddress roleName="WebRole_1">
        <Subnets>
          <Subnet name="TenantSubnet" />
        </Subnets>
      </InstanceAddress>
    </AddressAssignments>
  </NetworkConfiguration>
```

2) ServiceDefinition.csdef

```
  <WebRole name="WebRole_1" vmsize="ExtraSmall">
    <Imports />
    <Startup>
        <!--omit here, generated <Task> by Add-AzureNodeWebRole -->
    </Startup>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
  </WebRole>
```

3) my VNet Config (Get-AzureVNetConfig)

```
  <VirtualNetworkConfiguration>
    <Dns>
      <DnsServers>
          <!-- omit here <DnsServer> -->
      </DnsServers>
    </Dns>
    <LocalNetworkSites>
      <LocalNetworkSite name="Local Network">
        <AddressSpace>
          <AddressPrefix>172.16.0.0/12</AddressPrefix>
        </AddressSpace>
      </LocalNetworkSite>
    </LocalNetworkSites>
    <VirtualNetworkSites>
      <VirtualNetworkSite name="myVNet" Location="Central US">
        <AddressSpace>
          <AddressPrefix>10.107.235.0/28</AddressPrefix>
          <AddressPrefix>10.107.238.0/28</AddressPrefix>
        </AddressSpace>
        <Subnets>
          <Subnet name="GatewaySubnet">
            <AddressPrefix>10.107.238.0/28</AddressPrefix>
          </Subnet>
          <Subnet name="TenantSubnet">
            <AddressPrefix>10.107.235.0/28</AddressPrefix>
          </Subnet>
        </Subnets>
        <DnsServersRef>
          <!-- omit here <DnsServerRef/>-->
        </DnsServersRef>
        <Gateway profile="Large">
          <ConnectionsToLocalNetwork>
            <LocalNetworkSiteRef name="Local Network">
              <Connection type="Dedicated" />
            </LocalNetworkSiteRef>
          </ConnectionsToLocalNetwork>
        </Gateway>
      </VirtualNetworkSite>
    </VirtualNetworkSites>
  </VirtualNetworkConfiguration>
```

4) Virtual Network diagram

[image]